Assign numbers to character values
I am trying to assign numeric values to survey responses for easier analysis. I have responses that are "Agree", "Don't Know", and "Disagree" so I am trying to assign them values of 1, 2, and 3 respectively.
Trying to do this without individually changing everything in my dataset.
I am stumped. I tried
as.numeric(factor(practice$col1))

This gave me numbers from 1-5 so not what I'm looking for.
And I tried
practice$col1 |> as.integer(factor(), levels(c("Agree", "Disagree", "Don't Know")), ordered = TRUE)

This changed everything to NAs

If you get 5 factor levels instead of expected 3, perhaps start by checking actual unique values, e.g. unique(practice$col1).  Your 2nd snippet translates to as.integer(practice$col1, factor(), ...) , did you mean something like practice$col1 |> factor(levels = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Don't Know"), ordered = TRUE) |> as.integer() instead?

Using case_when() inside of a mutate() could get you to your desired output like so:
library(dplyr)
practice |>
    mutate(
        RespValue = case_when(
            col1 == 'Agree' ~ 1,
            col1 == 'Disagree' ~ 2,
            .default = 3
        )
)

